# How to export & import F&B Client in Openbravo

Tags: openbravo

I have exported F&B Client and trying to import as 'Demo' client but it throws an error. While, i was able to do an import & export of other clients.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Usman

Answer (score 0):

F&B Client is given by Openbravo as demo Client.

*Same client can not imported twice even if it is renamed with some other name. Since all the uuid will become duplicate. Really if you want to import the F&B Client then first you need to remove the client and import it again..*

Comment: Thanks. U r absoutely right. I am now trying to find alternates because we have training requirement for to give isolated F&B client to multiple users. Do let me know if you have any thoughts/ideas. thanks, Usman